# Разобрать XML в PHP на SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

Как можно получить все значения элементов "name" для файла со структурой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>    
    <ftpman port="1111" >
    <Upload name = "nameagent"
            pattern = "metods"
            applyMethod = "SET"
            ftpServer = "server.ru"
            ftpServerPort = "21"
            ftpSeparator = "/"
            ftpRemoteVerification = "false"
            ftpUser = "user"
            reconnect = "true"
            ftpDstDir = "/make/"
            ftpCacheDir = "/cache/"
            ftpActiveMode = "true"
            ftpTimeout = "10"
            ftpFileType = "binary"
            saveTime = "false"
            srcDir = "dirs"
            fileMask = "csv$"
            delayBetween = "10"
            zip = "false"
            gzip = "false"
            unpack = "false"
            lagInterval = "0"
            queueWarnInterval = "1800"
            queueWarnOn = "20"
            queueWarnOff = "0"
            slowStop = "true"/>
    <Load name = "nameagent"
            pattern = "metods"
            applyMethod = "SET"
            ftpServer = "server.ru"
            ftpServerPort = "21"
            ftpSeparator = "/"
            ftpRemoteVerification = "false"
            ftpUser = "user"
            reconnect = "true"
            ftpDstDir = "/make/"
            ftpCacheDir = "/cache/"
            ftpActiveMode = "true"
            ftpTimeout = "10"
            ftpFileType = "binary"
            saveTime = "false"
            srcDir = "dirs"
            fileMask = "csv$"
            delayBetween = "10"
            zip = "false"
            gzip = "false"
            unpack = "false"
            lagInterval = "0"
            queueWarnInterval = "1800"
            queueWarnOn = "20"
            queueWarnOff = "0"
            slowStop = "true"
    />
    </ftpman>
```

Comment: А где тут элементы name? Вы имели ввиду атрибуты?

Comment: Да извиняйте ошибся. Я про атрибуты name

Comment: и как вы пробывали это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим весь ва XML находится в переменной `$xmlString`. Если загрузить его в *SimpleXML*, можно получить доступ к нужным узлам, адресуя их при помощи *XPath*. Например, для вашего случая можно перебрать все элементы с аттрибутами `name` (ну и потом брать нужные значения уже из аттрибутов найденных элементов)

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
$found = $sxml->xpath('//@name');
foreach ($found as $element) {
    print $element->name . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Почитайте также про [XPATH](http://www.raleigh.ru/XML/w3schools/xpath/)

Comment: Спасибо. Честно говоря я его использовал давненьки и совсем забыл что можно его использовать в таких делах.